# is it possible to inject my javascript to disable javascript inside any webpage using webview?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

i am working on disconnect or ghosty addon like in firefox for my custom browser to stop some tracking scripts inside various webpages, but failed to find any help to disable tracking inside all webpage that loads in a webview.

after some search i found way to stop track by remove sctript from webpages to load. 
But failed to find solution to remove all those scripts from loading inside webview, please help..

Answer (score 2):

Ok,so i found my solution to block only some of javascript in loading page with help of method **shouldInterceptRequest** of **WebViewClient**
i use simply return empty response without any data to load as usual as written in docs.

> Notify the host application of a resource request and allow the application to return the data.  If the return value is null, the WebView
>    will continue to load the resource as usual.  Otherwise, the return
>         response and data will be used.  NOTE: This method is called on a thread
>         other than the UI thread so clients should exercise caution
>         when accessing private data or the view system.

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
     if(myConditionFullFilled){
          return new WebResourceResponse("text/css", "UTF-8", null);
         } 
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a way for that.

But an easier and simple way would be:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Yazan, thank you for your suggestion, but it will block all javascript opened in webview, i need only some to block.